# Remove all stylings (border, glow) from textarea

Tags: css, forms, textarea, border

I want to remove the stylings from a textarea and leave it all white without any border or glow, if possible. I've tried with different stuff found here on SO, but nothing works (tried with FF and Chrome).

So, is it possible and if so how to do it?

[image]

**What I've tried so far:**

```css
textarea#story {
  // other stuff
  -moz-appearance:none;
  outline:0px none transparent;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a CSS reset?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The glow effect is most-likely controlled by box-shadow. In addition to adding what Pavel said, you can add the box-shadow property for the different browser engines.

```css
textarea {
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;

    resize: none; /*remove the resize handle on the bottom right*/
}
```

You may also try adding !important to prioritize this CSS.

Comment: You can also remove the resize handle on the bottom right with `resize: none;`

Comment: The answer is good, but not complete, this will not work properly if you will not add the focus modifier, such as

textarea:focus {
border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;

    resize: none;
}
Then it will work

Answer (score 42):

If you want to remove EVERYTHING :

```
textarea {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Add a "border-radius: 0;" if you are adding borders back in to git rid of the curves from the text form.

Comment: This answer is superior to the accepted answer because it included "resize: none" which the accepted answer is missing.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
textarea {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: Transparent;
        overflow: auto;
        outline: none;
      }
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/orozon/2/

Comment: Tried it but nothing happens :/

Comment: hm, i have no styling at all... did u try jsbin link?

Comment: Tried your jsbin and that works, but not for me in my code. I wonder if it has something to do with Twitter Bootstrap maybe? When I put "!important" after every line a lot of styling was removed but there is still a small, light border in the top, on the left and on the right (the bottom is white). Strange...

Comment: @holyredbeard have you tried applying the style above to the **:focus** selector?

Comment: `resize: none;` helps as well. +1 for jsbin link

Answer (score 1):

You want a  minimal `textarea` with no borders, or `resize`-drag-icon.

Both when not selected and when `focus`.

---

It's easy but you'll need to update `rows` attribute via **JS** as newlines are added or removed during text input.

Here is the **CSS**

```
textarea, textarea:focus
{
    font-family: "roboto","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; /* make your choice */
    font-size: 11px;                                                   /* make your choice */ 
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperarance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

in order to keep things working as expected (looking good) you have to programmatically set/update `textarea`'s attribute `rows` to the count of `\r\n` in the the `textarea` contents **plus 1** when the contents is set **and** when it's updated (user input / other)