# html element hide the square box around the already created curved border

Tags: html

[image: UNwanted blue border]

I have the following css for textarea

```
textarea {
    background: transparent;
    display: inline;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 1%;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 38px;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 1pt #8F4A11;
}
```

As you can see from the image, when I click on the text area, a blue border appears around the box. I'd like to remove the blue borde. Could I request guidance please?

Comment: Related duplicates - [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8622686/2930477) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17109702/2930477)... and [another one here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16156594/2930477)... Just make sure that when the input/textarea is in focus there is an obvious indicator, using `textarea:focus,input:focus { /*properties*/}`

Comment: @misterManSam I would have to disagree. All of the links focus on `box-shadow` while we cannot touch the `box-shadow` property here since it is part of the original style.

Comment: @asdf - The blue border pictured in the question is from Chrome and is removed with `outline: none` on focus. This is covered in other questions and [here is my example](https://jsbin.com/lumafo/edit?html,css,output) using the CSS above and removing the outline whilst adding a different color box shadow on focus. This is not a new question.

Comment: Thank you. Those examples come in handy in other places for me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `textarea:focus` element to your styles and remove the `border` and `outline` properties:

**CSS**

```
textarea:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7w76nwp/) demonstrating

Comment: Hello asdf - Is it possible to get the box shadow to have a radius to curve along the same border as the textbox?