# Disable highlighted underline in textarea when in focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, textarea

I have a textarea in a react app and currently when you click on it the bottom highlight is thicker than the rest, it looks like the picture below. How do I disable this and make the whole box highlight normally and uniformly?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all stylings (border, glow) from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109702/remove-all-stylings-border-glow-from-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS and the `:focus` selector to set the style when the control has focus. The following CSS will add a 2-pixel-wide border around a textarea control when it has focus.

```
textarea:focus {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that the bottom border is still thicker than the rest. I also tried making this !important.

Comment: There may be a box-shadow set as well, so you can try including `box-shadow: 0;`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the box-shadow either. Really not sure, none of the CSS that shows up when I inspect seems to be related either. Might have to do some more digging.

Comment: Are you using a UI framework? You can also try setting those properties in the `style` attribute of the textarea to see if it’s related to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Set border property as you need like below

```css
textarea {
border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .form-group.form-md-line-input .form-control.edited:not([readonly]) ~ label:after, .form-group.form-md-line-input .form-control.edited:not([readonly]) ~ .form-control-focus:after, .form-group.form-md-line-input .form-control:focus:not([readonly]) ~ label:after, .form-group.form-md-line-input .form-control:focus:not([readonly]) ~ .form-control-focus:after, .form-group.form-md-line-input .form-control.focus:not([readonly]) ~ label:after, .form-group.form-md-line-input .form-control.focus:not([readonly]) ~ .form-control-focus:after {
   background: none !important;
}
```

```
//If you send code i can help you.
```